# could not send the SMS message via Tropo

Tags: sms, tropo

We are using the TropoSharp to send SMS message to my phone. The weird part is that I didn't get any SMS message, rather I get a phone call and it is very short and I could not figure out what the person is talking over the phone.

By looking at the code, we could not figure out what's wrong:

```
            string voiceToken = "xxx";
        string messagingToken = "xxx";
        IDictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        parameters.Add("sendToNumber", "xxx");
        parameters.Add("sendFromNumber", "+1 201-xxx-04xx");
        string channel = Channel.Text;
        parameters.Add("channel", channel);
        string network = Network.SMS;
        parameters.Add("network", network);
        parameters.Add("msg", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("This is a test message from C#."));
        Tropo tropo = new Tropo();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string token = channel == Channel.Text ? messagingToken : voiceToken;
        doc.Load(tropo.CreateSession(token, parameters));
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + doc.SelectSingleNode("session/success").InnerText.ToUpper());
        Console.WriteLine("Token: " + doc.SelectSingleNode("session/token").InnerText);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Here is the http request (removed some sensitive information)

```
GET http://api.tropo.com/1.0/sessions?action=create&token=xxxxx&sendToNumber=xxx&sendFromNumber=+1%20201-xxx-xxxx&channel=TEXT&network=SMS&msg=This+is+a+test+message+from+C%23.& HTTP/1.1
Host: api.tropo.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

here is the response (I guess it only means that request is submitted successful):

```
<session><success>true</success><token>xxxx</token><id>5c994e73ab85ff47fd1af4ffd4002e00
```

Any idea where we did wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using the scripting approach, not WebAPI, right?  Can you post the script that your application is using?  It's my understanding that when you create a session, you're just passing variables up to your script.  Your script might be completely ignoring those variables, and just making a voice call.

I agree about your last point.  That response just tells you that it succeeded in creating the session.  It doesn't return any additional information about other steps of the process.

Comment: above is our C# code and http request format. I would think that it is web api, right?

Comment: Not necessarily.  The code you're using looks like it's intended for the scripting approach.  The names aren't 100% obvious.  You still contact Tropo's server using a web-based api.  But the WebAPI approach means that your server receives commands from Tropo.  To find out, open your account with Tropo, click the Applications button in the header and look at the display name of your application.  For example, mine says "Prod API - Main (WebAPI)"

Answer (score 0):

There are two tokens for your application, one for voice and one for messaging. Are you using the one for messaging?  Also, outbound messaging is not turned on be default for your application.  You have to contact Tropo support to turn it on for development. They may require you to put some money in your account to do this, but they will not charge you unless you start abusing this feature during development.